# What is this symbol: $ \| . \| _ 2 ^ 2 $

Tags: linear-algebra

We can quantify complexity using the **$L_2$ regularization** formula, which defines the regularization term as the sum of the squares of all the feature weights:

$$L_2 \text{ regularization term } =\, \|w\|_2^2 \,= w^2_1 + w^2_2+\dots+w^2_n$$

What is this $\|w\|_2^2$ with 2 up and down called? I tried to search for it but couldn't find anything. Would appreciate any help on what this is and how it operates, thanks.

Comment: See: [Norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Notation)

Comment: It's worth noting that the upper $2$ is not part of the symbol. The upper $2$ means that $\|w\|_2$ is squared.

Comment: Yes but why does it already have a lower 2 there, what does it mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see $\alpha=\|x\|_p^n$, then $\alpha$ is the [$\ell_p$ norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Definition) of the vector $x$ raised the the $n$th power.  Specifically,
$$
\|x\|_p^n = \left(\sum_{i=1}^k x_i^p\right)^{(n/p)}
$$
if $x\in R^k.$  For $n=2$ and $p=2$, this reduces to 
$$
\|x\|_2^2 = \sum_{i=1}^k x_i^2.
$$

Comment: If the typographical difference between $||x||$ and $\|x\|$ is not conspicuous enough for you, look at the difference between $$\|x\|\|y\|$$ (coded as \|x\|\|y\|) and $$ ||x|| ||y|| $$ (coded as ||x|| ||y||).  That is why I edited this answer.

Answer (score 2):

It means the Euclidean Vector Space, or more simply, it means take the magnitude of vector w.

You can read about this further on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnitude_(mathematics))